# Why does macOS not assign unique identifiers to files?

Tags: macos, filesystem

I want to preface this question by disclosing I know next to nothing about computer architecture, storage and operating systems.

For a personal project, I'm trying to make a roadmap for how to make a small helper program that will enable linking to annotations in PDFs.

I have hit a small roadblock, though. Say I have a PDF called Doc. I'm reading and I make an annotation called Annot. Because the Annot is contained in Doc, I would first have to link to Doc's path:

```
Path > Doc > Annot
```

This could work by linking to the doc's path. There is one problem with this, though. I often reorganize my PDFs as my collection grows, so a link like that would soon break. Which leads to my question:

Why do macOS by default not assign each file on your harddrive a UUID for easy recall? In such a way, I would be able to link like:

1. Link to Doc path with UUID as argument
2. If path doesn't contain a document with Doc's UUID, search for a document with that UUID and go to path
3. Return Doc

I think I might be able to make a similar solution by assigning a UUID to a documents metadata.

So to sum up: Is there any reason this wouldn't be included by default? Is there any reason this would be a bad idea?

Comment: I suspect this is an X-Y problem. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve overall, as there may be a better way to do it. Do you want to create some kind of index of annotations made in multiple PDFs? Or you just want to include clickable links in your app to annotations in a set of PDFs?

Comment: Each file is already assigned an integer unique to the volume where the file is stored. This is referred to as an inode. There a many  answers on stack exchange which explain why accessing a file by its inode would not be practical. See for example [Open file by inode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092559/open-file-by-inode) and [Can a file be retrieved by its inode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92816/can-a-file-be-retrieved-by-its-inode).

Comment: @benwiggy To be honest, I'm still not sure excactly what I want to achieve, yet. Right now I'm mostly trying to figure out what is feasible. Right now, my workflow when I'm reading textbooks is: 1. Read and highlight relevant information
2. Review highlights
3. Write notes and study-questions based on highlights with a reference to where I made a given highlight (e.g.: "How was civil service implemented in the UK during WWII?" [SotU 1944, FDR, p. 3])
I figured it could be a fun personal project to hack together a text editor so I could make a direct link to the highlight instead.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thank you very much! I'll look into inodes! Quick followup question: I've been looking around for a quick introduction to the macOS file system. Do anyone know of any reference that is suitable for a complete novice?

Comment: @Oeyaas Probably best to work out what you want to achieve first, then find out how to do it. Creating your own text editor, as a complete novice, will be very lengthy process -- and there are already many excellent ones. There are also ways of cataloguing and index groups of PDFs, which may be more useful.

Comment: Tools like https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/devonthink might help, actually. Also, please keep in mind that development questions are usually off-topic here and should be asked on StackOverflow instead.

Comment: @benwiggy Thank you for your advice and your patience! I’m still very new to programming and app development and am basically using this project as an exercise to build on my very rudimentary skills and practice sketching out ideas. I obviously need to keep practicing! :)

Comment: @nohillside That looks pretty much excactly like what I’m looking for! And I apologize for asking an off-topic question. This is my first time using StackExchange/StackOverflow - I’m gonna read the community guidelines more carefully in the future!

Comment: *a UUID for easy recall?*  That's a novel idea !

Answer (score 3):

Bookmark remains persistent across reboots. "File reference URL" (`file:///.file/id=367.27/`) is not reboot safe.
If user relocates a file, both "String-based path" (`/Users/me/a.txt`) and "Path-based URL" (`file://localhost/Users/me/a.txt`) break too.

> ### Locating Files Using Bookmarks
>
> If you want to save the location of a file persistently, use the bookmark capabilities of [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl). A bookmark is an opaque data structure, enclosed in an NSData object, that describes the location of a file. Whereas path- and file reference URLs are potentially fragile between launches of your app, a bookmark can usually be used to re-create a URL to a file even in cases where the file was moved or renamed.
>
> To create a bookmark for an existing URL, use the [`bookmarkDataWithOptions:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417795-bookmarkdatawithoptions) method of `NSURL`. Specifying the [`NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlbookmarkcreationoptions/nsurlbookmarkcreationsuitableforbookmarkfile) option creates an [`NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata) object suitable for saving to disk. Listing 2-3 shows a simple example implementation that uses this method to create a bookmark data object.

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10)

Comment: Thank you very much for sending me in the right direction! I'll look into NSURLS!